# Group Membership Discounts using Group Based pricing

Tags: drupal, civimember

I am trying to add some functionality to membership pricing where the more people we can get to sign up at a time the bigger the discount they will get. So for instance:

1 - 4 members, $110 each, No discount, $110 - $440
5 - 10 members, $93 each, 15% discount, $465 - $930
11 - 20 members, $82 each, 25% discount, $902 - $1,640
21 - 40 members, $71 each, 35% discount, $1,491 - $2,840
40+ members, $55 each, 50% discount, $2,251 & up

How would I go about adding this to the membership sign up page?  I've installed and enabled the group-based pricing extension

To be clear it would only apply to new members (new signups). And they would need the ability to say how many memberships they want.

Comment: Hi - Are you by any chance on Drupal?

Comment: yes Drupal 7.43

Answer (score 1):

You can use webform_civicrm module - but it will be quite some config!

Something like:

- add a Drupal field - how many members would you like to sign up?
- make as as many contacts in the civicrm tab as you need (you may need to bump up a parameter in webform_civicrm code) - you can make one (add all the fields you want) then in the webform tab -> clone
- use conditionals to show the correct number of contacts
- make sure you have relationship to primary contact (something like Member sign-up by)
- make sure your membership type filters down to inherit by relationship
- the monies... will be the default $ in your Membership Type config - however - you can add your own contribution field in webform and use conditionals (or jQuery to get the grand total $ right - based on the # of members field the user selected

Good luck setting that up! Please do report back!

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'll keep you posted on the progress.  We may still be a ways from getting there, but I'll definitely check back in